# this 'while' clause does not ground

Tags: c++, gcc, warning

Возникает предупреждение при компиляции
`this 'while' clause does not ground`
В этом куске кода

```
while(temp != nullptr);
{
    if(!temp->child.isEmpty())
    {
        node = temp->child.front();
        return *this;
    }

    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Не могу понять что бы это значило, проходя дебагером, он просто перескакивает его и больше ничего не делает (стоят брейкпоинты внутри и после него, но ни одна из них не выполняется), при этом программа виснет

В гугле ничего внятного не нашел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предупреждение говорит о том что цикл у вас не закончится, то есть он будет бесконечным:

```
while(temp != nullptr); // <- из-за этой точки с запятой
{
    if(!temp->child.isEmpty())
    {
        node = temp->child.front();
        return *this;
    }

    temp = temp->next;
}
```

То есть вы (видимо по ошибке) написали цикл `while` с пустым телом, поэтому значение `temp` никогда не меняется и цикл становится бесконечным.

Comment: Спасибо, пора прекращать кодить по 20 часов)